# Why is "annotatedClasses" needed if there is @Entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

Hello I'm building spring-hibernate application. Do i realy need configuration from below ?

```
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>org.fixus.springer.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

I've set annotation-driven in my root-context.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.fixus.springer" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.fixus.springer.model" />
```

Now shouldn't hibernate automaticly take everything from this packages with annotation @Entity and convert it to table ? As for now without annotatedClasses he won't create a table from a entity

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Use the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html), Luke!*

> [...]Example for an AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean definition:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>test.package.Foo</value>
            <value>test.package.Bar</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> Or when using classpath scanning for autodetection of entity classes:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>
</bean>
```

As you can see you have a choice between defining all classes explicitly or only the package for scanning. `<context:component-scan/>` does not recognize Hibernate/JPA annotations and hence has no effect.